# When minimize the app all notifications disappear

Tags: android, notifications, ionic3

I’m building `ionic3` application to receive push notifications , I’m using `phonegap-plugin-push` , now if notification comes while app is foreground and I minimize the app all notifications disappear from the bar !!
any solution for this problem ?